Do United paid upgrades to first class (from economy) count for PQP PQF stuff?
So I'm Premier Gold, flying domestic, looking at a $199 upgrade to first class from a $112 Economy (91 PQP). (Paid first class is $329 - but only PQP292)
Does the amount paid for the upgrade count towards PQP?
Would upgrading bypass the usual tax that reduces the dollar paid to PQP? So, would I get 199 PQP + 91 PQP from paying the upgrade fee? (Instead of only 292 from a paid first class without upgrade.)

Cash upgrades do count towards PQP. They do not count towards PQF (in the sense that they don't change the number of PQF you would have already received - 1 per flight regardless of class), nor do they earn 'Miles' (RDM).
Whether buying Economy and upgrading is a better option than simply buying First in the first place depends on a number of factors. It's possible that by the time you get to the upgrade step the price will have increased. Upgrading will also result in you missing out on additional miles that you would have received for the ticket (due to the upgrade price not earning miles).
Note that whilst the upgrade fee will earn PQP, it will NOT show in the PQP calculations for the flight listed on the United website/app.  The PQP for the upgrade will post separately after the flight.  It's worth keeping an eye on it to make sure the PQP do post correctly - in my experience they do normally post automatically, but not always (in which case an email to United will get things sorted).

I find it easy to earn miles by finding cheap airfare, but PQP seems a bit harder - since for a flight to the same airport, you can get the same amount of miles but a different PQP if you pay more.

Miles are also based on the price of the ticket.  With no status, Miles earnt will be exactly 5 times PQP (but on the base flight price only).
